# What are the Clouds floating in the foreground?

Tags: fallout-4

They usually appear low, you have to look at your feet, and at other times can obstruct your view.  They are oriented to a compass heading.  They vary in size, shape and color.  I have tried to follow them, even to the edge of the map. Then the next time I turn around to see their heading, they are gone. I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot you could share? Also, is it the render distance of the game (trees and bushes popping into view, ground details focusing, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I think I've seen something similar on Xbox One. (Not sure what your platform is.)

It appears to be a bug associated with effects for the Power Armor's Jet Pack. Getting out of the Power Armor usually clears it. (It stays cleared after you get back in, until the next time the bug is triggered.)

I *think* I've seen it in third-person view as well, but I'm not sure. (If I have, it's only *after* having triggered it in first-person initially.) I'm also not sure what exactly triggers the bug, since it doesn't happen *every* time I use the Jet Pack in first-person view, but it does occur rather frequently.

[Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_%28Fallout_4%29#Bugs) has confirmation that the bug is on PC as well. Their comments say it happens in first-person view and can also be cleared by removing and re-equipping the Power Armor's chest plate.

> While in first person, the smoke from the power armor's jet-pack won't go away until you re-enter the suit or remove and equip the chest piece.